# jQuery - Remove table row, if any cell contains a value between X and Y

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying show/hide a list of shops, based on their zip-code.
The data is loaded through php on a WP site, and I'm trying to create a script, with which I can hide/show shops based on the users choice of area.
For this, I need to show shops with a zip-code between eg. 8000 and 9000, 
whilst all other shops are hidden.

I've tried this, but to no avail.

```
$("#prices td").each(function() { 
    if ($(this).val() >= 8000 && $(this).val() <= 9000){
        $(this).parent().hide();
};
```

[Here's a picture of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWTCM.png)

Here's a snip of the php behind the table(edited, to reduce size)

```
<tbody>
<?php foreach( $results as $result ){ ?>
<tr data-id="<?php echo esc_attr( $result->feed_id ) ?>">
    <td>
        <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $result->store_logo, 'full' ) ?>
    </td>
    <td class="price">
        <?php echo compare_format_currency_number( $result->price ) ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $result->store_zipcode ?>
    </td>
        <?php endif; ?>                             
</tr>
<?php }?>
</tbody>
```

At the moment, there's only two shops, but more will be added, and I need to able to show/hide them based on a selected zip-code range, predefined in buttons.

Advice on how to smoothly create a transition in showing/hiding the rows, when changing region would also be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I would like to see the HTML of the table.But looking at your code I would tell you to use `$(this).find('your zip column').text()` and `$(this).closest().hide()

Comment: Edited it to include some of the markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work fine for me:
https://jsfiddle.net/y3llowjack3t/aj7rfk0m/

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="prices0" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="prices1" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="prices2" value="8001"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="prices3" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JQuery:

```
$("input[id^=prices]").each(function() { 
    if ($(this).val() >= 8000 && $(this).val() <= 9000){
        $(this).parent().hide();
    }
});
```

Another way if you are not using inputs:
https://jsfiddle.net/y3llowjack3t/aj7rfk0m/1/

```
$("td[id^=prices]").each(function() { 
    if (parseInt($(this).text()) >= 8000 && parseInt($(this).text())<= 9000) {
        $(this).parent().hide();
    }
});
```

or:

```
$("td[id^=prices]").each(function() { 
    if ($(this).text() >= 8000 && $(this).text() <= 9000){
        $(this).parent().hide();
        }
});
```

Comment: I see that the .val property is probably wrong, since the zip-code is just text in the <td>, and not the value of an input-field.

Comment: @DanielPaaske Yes, use text, <td> doesnt have a val() property. $("td[id^=prices]").each(function() { 
    if ($(this).text() >= 8000 && $(this).text() <= 9000){
        $(this).parent().hide();
  }
});

Comment: Thanks. It still won't work though. Am I targeting the <td> wrong?
The #prices id is a div 8 levels above the td, but all the levels down to the td have generic classes.
You can have a look here: http://iloverep.dk/produkt/iphone-6s-plus-original-skaerm/

Comment: if your class is price than you need to use the class selector: $(".price") See updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y3llowjack3t/aj7rfk0m/2/

Comment: The "prices" is an ID of a div, inside there's a div, another div, another div, antoher div, a table, a tbody, a tr and then the td. Would I have explicitly run through the entire path? Or is it fine just doing it like #prices td?

Comment: You should be able to use selector $("td.price"), if you do $("prices td) it will hide every td in prices  that meet your criteria, so if some of those TDs contain a value that is greater than 8k and lesser than 9k it would hide them too.

Comment: Mate, I really appreciate your help! In this case, it doesn't matter, because they will be the only td's containing pure numerics.
And now it works! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @DanielPaaske No Problem